# Binance API: symbol price ticker. What delimiter for several symbols?

Tags: api, binance

Binance provides good API documentation but in some cases, it looks either incomplete or unclear at least.
Symbol Price Ticker: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#symbol-price-ticker

**Question:** is there a way to get prices just for several symbols (more than one but not a complete list)? It looks illogical but seems Binance handles either a single symbol or an entire list at once. Attempts to use different delimiter (like: ",", ";", "+", "|", etc) leads to an error:

*request*: `api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=DOGEUSDT,ETHBTC`

*response*: `Illegal characters found in parameter 'symbol'; legal range is '^[A-Z0-9-_.]{1,20}$'`

As a result, integration code is not optimal - developers have to send several similar requests or extract required data from hundreds of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, there is no way to select just a set of symbols. If you want one request then you need to fetch all.

Binance has updated the /api/v3/exchangeInfo endpoint recently to take a list of symbols in this format ["DOGEUSDT","ETHBTC"], so maybe they will add that to other endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

if you use 2 or more parameters add the letter "S" to the symbol
ex request 2 param:[https://www.binance.me/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=[%22STMXUSDT%22,%22BTCUSDT%22]](https://www.binance.me/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=%5B%22STMXUSDT%22,%22BTCUSDT%22%5D)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nice! This works as well. https://www.binance.me/api/v3/ticker/price?symbols=[%22DOGEUSDT%22,%22BTCUSDT%22]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I've changed my timer from grabbing every 1 second to every 5 seconds, sending 5 requests in a `for` loop. It's annoying and unnecessary to create multiple objects for the same data:

```
QString symbols[5] = { "BTCUSDT", "BNBUSDT", ... etc };

for(auto symbol : symbols){
    GetData(symbol);
}
```

The QString is of course from QT. Without it, you can use std::string.